# Can you use a field comment/description as an alias inside of a (MySQL) sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know if I'm wording it right or if it can be done?

What I would like to do, is return in a query the comment/description (whatever you want to call it)...

So for example, if I have a field called FName and its comment/description is First Name, I would like to return that inside of the query instead of giving some awful looking field name which if I'm not mistaken would also be a compromise of security in a sort of way...

This is if I use it on a webpage where I would be giving out the actual field name which is why instead of typing as for each one I'd like to just pull back the description in the query if possible?

Comment: I see you can pull it back from the schema in a separate type of query which looks like it would be one hell of a job to join to regular tables, like more effort than it would be worth kind of thing unless I'm missing something

Comment: "which if I'm not mistaken would also be a compromise of security in a sort of way..." - no, not really. If someone already has the ability to run commands and queries against your database (i.e. where having the column names would be useful) then they won't benefit from being told what the column names are in normal output.

Comment: I could have sworn it was mentioned in many books and to not use actual field names when presenting data like on websites, so its recommended not to use "first name" as a field name if that's what you'll be putting the website for example...

Not necessarily a security risk but information that shouldn't be given out to potential hackers is I might be a better way of saying it...

Comment: You could output two result sets - one holding the metadata, and another with the actual data directly below in the same order, so that the metadata looks like headers.

I'm not sure why you would do that though, it seems like an xy problem.

Comment: FWIW, I would leave the query as fname, and handle any further renaming in application code

Comment: I was thinking if there was an easy way to get at the info that I could use to put that information into form fields so I wouldn't have to type it out each time, just once in the database and have it pulled from there without actually giving the field name out to the public kind of thing...

Answer (score 2):

You can get the comment without having to type it, using a query like:

```
SELECT COLUMN_COMMENT 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'myschema' 
  AND TABLE_NAME = 'mytable'
  AND COLUMN_NAME = 'fname'
```

Any metadata can be queried from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/columns-table.html and its sister pages in the documentation.

Keep in mind that executing queries against the INFORMATION_SCHEMA very frequently is known to cause performance problems. It's usually better to store metadata as static data in your application code.

Comment: That's what I'm looking at right now was going to try to see if I could tie it easily into queries in an automated way, for one reason or another it keeps tripping an error which doesn't give any information, clicking ignore gets me the results but it doesn't show up always. I'm wondering if it has something to do with those performance issues you mentioned...

Comment: I would not expect it to give intermittent blank results. Performance issues means it takes a longer time, but it will give the same result each time. I have no idea how you have written your code, so I can't give any other advice based on your description.

Comment: But I repeat my recommendation to _avoid_ querying metadata in information_schema for every query you need to run! Cache the column metadata.

Comment: Thought I had a simple solution but realized I was an idiot and didn't think it through...

I wouldn't need to create some kind of alias table I guess and fill it with table and field names, then give it alias's I would use